# Why does .fetchall() method return empty list in this situation?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, python-3.6

basically the problem is that the fetch all method is returning an empty list , and Ive checked outside of this method to see if the values i entered witch is   `ronaldb` 
 and `123456` currently reside inside of the `login` `TABLE` and they do , so i believe there is something wrong with the `signin_check` method that im not seeing. Ive seen other problems on the website with a similar problem , but none solves my problem.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('login.db')
c = conn.cursor()
def signin_check():
    global obj
    username_information = obj.username.get()
    password_information = obj.password.get()
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM login WHERE password =:password and user = :user" , {'password' : str(username_information) , 'user' : str(password_information)})

    if c.fetchall() == []:
        print (False)
    else:
        print(True)
```

## The code I used to check the contents

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM login WHERE user = :user" , {'password' : '123456' , 'user' : 'ronaldb'})
print(c.fetchall())
```

## The results

```
[('qeqwe', 'qweqwewq', 'ronaldb', '123456', 'multiple', 'Dr.', 'ee')]
```

## Here is the code i used to create the table

```
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE login (
                        first text,
                        last text,
                        user text ,
                        password text,
                        accounttype text,
                        title text,
                        buisness text



    )""")
```

Comment: You might want to print out the value of username and password to see what's being passed to `execute`.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ i did exactly that and the results are listed in the answer

Comment: Wait, why are u using `:= user`. Use more regular syntax. like ? to represent vars in your sqlite query. that is known to work

Comment: I mean, from `obj`...

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ the 2 obj attributes are tkinter entrys , Ive checked those , also , i can see what im inputing inside of the entry , and i convert it over to a string after

Comment: c.execute("SELECT * FROM login WHERE password = ? and user = ? " , ('123456' ,  'ronaldb'))

Comment: hmm, not sure if this might help but `c.execute("SELECT * FROM login WHERE password = ? AND user = ? " , ('123456' , 'ronaldb'))`  I capitalized the and

Comment: @MichaelIlie I just tried it and still same result , but its crazy because in the same script , it prints out the values if i do the search outside of the method

Comment: in the `c.execute(...)` statement in your posted code, you populate the password dictionary entry with user_name data and the user dict entry with password data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM login WHERE password =:password and user = :user" , {'password' : str(username_information) , 'user' : str(password_information)})
```

this line of code here. You put user info where there should be password info and vice versa

Comment: click this as answered, so i know i did. Thanks